# Select table row as object property

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Can pdo return a table row as an object, and can a property of that object be the result of a `SELECT` on another table using a `JOIN`?

```
$STH = $this->Con->query("SELECT table1.*, table2.* AS table2row FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id");

$resultObj = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I have been able to extract a single column from table2, but I want the whole row to exist as a property.

Also, can I `SELECT` another table row as an object property with a second table join using the same method?

```
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.table3_id = table3.id
```

And the result in JSON.

```
return json_encode($resultObj, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)

[
    {
        "id": 1, "title": "Table 1 title data", "table2": 1, "table3": 100, 
        "table2row": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Table 2 row title data"
        },
        "table3row": {
            "id": 100,
            "title": "Table 2 row title data"
        }
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

I understand two `SELECT` statements and a `foreach` can achieve the same result, but I'd like to do this using one query if it's more efficient both for me to write and the server to execute.